# Who chooses the Chosen One?

Tags: jedi, the-force, star-wars

So the old Jedi legend tells of a Chosen One who will bring balance to the Force. What I'm curious about is - why the "Chosen" One?  **Who supposedly does the choosing?** The Force, as a conscious entity that can choose stuff? The Jedi Order? Some deity? Where does the "Chosen" bit come from?

Comment: [The Maker](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/110807/20774) chooses

Comment: @Richard Twist: Vader was supposed to be a Droid messiah :)

Comment: The Force, without doubt...

Comment: @MishaRosnach - SPOILER TAGS!

Comment: Bill Murray chooses.

Comment: A man chooses, a slave obeys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to *Clone Wars* cartoon (specifically, "*Ghosts of Mortis*" episode), it's the Force.

Why?

Because to confirm if Anakin is the Chosen one, he had to be brought to [The Ones (presumably evolved Celestials) on Mortis](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Ones), who literally represented the Force and its Light and Dark side.

In addition, the Jedi don't seem to believe in deities, so it couldn't be that. Everything flows from the Force. Very Zen :P

---

<sub>Yes, that was the point at which I decided (once I learned of it) not to watch *Clone wars*</sub>

<sub>So much for Dumbledore's "It is our choices, Harry, that show what we truly are, far more than our abilities". Star Wars is **clearly** not in Harry Potter universe, unlike E.T. :)</sub>

Comment: Hmm.. +1 for an interesting link.  It doesn't seem to imply, however, that the Force is an entity with a conscious intent.  After all, here we have a Son and a Daughter, who are capable of tearing the universe asunder and, yet, who got their light and dark powers by simply bathing in and drinking some forbidden knowledge water.  I'm not sure any of it implies that the Force itself is capable of choosing anything.  If anything, it seems to imply that it isn't.  PS. What a weird Biblical insertion into the Star Wars universe.  I can see why you didn't want to keep watching it.

Comment: @MishaRosnach - the rest of the canon implies that the Force can have intent. Darth SIdious talks explicitly about the Force "Striking back" - full intent there - in New Disney canon novel "Tarkin"

Comment: What's the context for that? That seems closer to what might be my answer. A stumbling block for me in the Force doing the choosing is - if the Force can choose someone, why can't it just "unchoose" any bad guys who are screwing with it? They seem pretty powerful. And if power isn't the result of the "choosing," then what exactly does the Force's "choosing" do?

Comment: @MishaRosnach - Context was Darth Plagueis. It's extremely likely he was thinking about Anakin's creation.

Comment: So then Sidious thought that the Force itself is beginning to fight the Sith?

Comment: @MishaRosnach - Plagueis AND Sidious. Who are we to argue?

Comment: Found an interesting quote by Plagueis when talking to Sidious - *"Dark times don't simply emerge, Sidious. Enlightened beings, guiding intelligences manipulate events to bring about a storm that will deliver power into the hands of an elite group willing to make the hard choices the Republic fears to make. Beings may elect their leaders, but the Force has elected us."* It seems that he thinks the Force "chose" them.  Now I'm thinking that the idea of a "Chosen One" may be a matter of two different religions each thinking that the messiah is theirs - without necessarily any intent to be found.

Comment: @MishaRosnach - I actulaly interpret that last statement simply as a Sith Lord being a self-aggrandizing megalomaniac with delusions of grandeur :)

Comment: Oh? What happened to "who are we to argue?" :-}

Comment: @MishaRosnach - I got delusions of grandeur too?

Comment: **Plagueis**: "Do you fancy yourself extraordinary?"
**Palpatine**: "I only meant that I want to live an extraordinary life."
**Plagueis**: "Make no apologies for your desires."

Comment: What does "literally represented the Force and its Light and Dark side" mean in this context? I mean, SPOILER ALERT both the Son and the Daughter end up dying, but the light side and dark side don't die with them. Also, at one point the Father says to the Son "You have done what is forbidden. You've chosen the dark side and allowed it to feed your anger and desire for power." This implies the Son *fell* to the dark side, so he isn't just some kind of timeless avatar of it.